# Synthesized copy property does not get deallocated with ARC

Tags: objective-c, ios

in my project I'm managing several *Drawing* objects. I'm trying to add a copy of a *SmartPath* object to a drawing object. This works. But when the drawing gets deallocated the *SmartPath* does not. I have put some extra code in the dealloc of the *Drawing* to explicitly set clear the pointer to the *SmartPath*. For some reason this works (the retain count was 1). I know I can probably copy the SmartPath and assign that to a strong parameter to fix this leak. But I'm relatively new to IOS and want to know how to use the copy parameters properly in combination with ARC.

Here is the code:

**Drawing.h:**

```
@interface Drawing : NSObject{
@private
    SmartPath* rawLinePath;         //path that is build up from straight lines between input points
    SmartPath* smoothLinePath;      //smoothened version of rawLinePath
}


@property(atomic,copy)SmartPath* rawLinePath;
@property(atomic,copy)SmartPath* smoothLinePath;
```

**Drawing.m**

```
@implementation Drawing
@synthesize rawLinePath;
@synthesize smoothLinePath;



-(id)init
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {        
        [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(pointMonitor) 
                                 toTarget:self 
                               withObject:nil];  
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)dealloc{
    rawLinePath=nil;
}
```

**SmartPath.m**

```
/*
 * Init - set all variables in the correct state
 */
-(id)init
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {        
        visible=TRUE;
        color = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
        width = SMARTPATH_LINE_WIDTH;
        path = CGPathCreateMutable();
        lock = [[NSLock alloc]init];
    }
    return self;
}

/*
 * dealloc - clean up after self 
 */
-(void)dealloc{
    CGPathRelease(path);
}

/*
 * copy method to be able to pass a SmartPath to a copy property
 */
-(id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone{
    SmartPath *pathCopy = [[SmartPath allocWithZone: zone] init];
    pathCopy.visible =visible;
    pathCopy.color = color;
    pathCopy.width = width;
    return pathCopy;
}
```

I hope any of you knows the answer to this problem.
Best regards

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is your call to `-detachNewThreadSelector:toTarget:withObject:`. This retains `target`, which is `self`, and does not release it until `pointMonitor` exits. I suspect this never happens, so you've effectively created a retain loop.

You should almost never use `-detachNewThreadSelector:toTarget:withObject:`. It can create an unbounded number of threads. Instead, you should generally use dispatch queues, `NSTimer`, `NSOperation` or other async mechanisms. `NSThread` objects are generally only appropriate for long-lived producer/consumer threads (and usually those are still handled better with the newer tools like dispatch queues).

I'm not certain what `pointMonitor` does, but is there any reason it needs its own thread at all? You can do a lot of very good Cocoa development and never fork a thread. Could you use an `NSTimer` here? Note that most of these techniques retain their target until they fire (just like `NSThread`). If they didn't, you'd crash when they fired.

Without knowing what you're trying to do, I'm not certain which approach to recommend. You may want to put that together as a new question.

Comment: There is no problem with the thread I created. pointMonitor does exit and releases the retained object through arc. I read a little more and find that copy properties are no longer supported with ARC. The compiler fails to warn me about this unfortunately. I think this creates a double retain when assigning where on one hand it is released by ARC and the other has to be done by explicitly setting to nil. The multiple threads are done to reduce the the time I block the UI thread. I do not want to create threads in the UI thread, but that's not the issue here. This actually closes it for me

Comment: What do you mean by "copy properties are no longer supported with ARC?"

Comment: I'm sorry I can't find where I have read that anymore. I guess that's not true

Answer (score 0):

By not starting instance variable names with an underscore, you end up with code where you never know whether you are using an accessor method or an instance variable. As a result, you can never be sure whether a copy is made or not.

If you do that in other places, there's a good chance that a reference to your SmartPath object gets stuck somewhere. And what are you doing creating NSLock objects? Do you need to do anything that @synchronized can't do with much less code?

And if you use a newer Xcode version, get rid of all the instance variables and @synthesize statements. Just declare the properties.

And excuse me, but detaching a thread from an init method is just sick.